# Wave equation that becomes elliptic on a bounded domain (sign-changing coefficient)

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, hyperbolic-pde

I'm looking for results on this kind of problems:
$$ \partial_{tt}^2 u - \partial_x(a(x) \partial_x) = f,$$
$$u(t=0) = u_0, \quad \partial_t u(t=0) = u_1,$$
where $a$ changes sign: $a(x)= -c^2 < 0$ for $x \in \Omega$ a bounded open set of $\mathbb R^d$ and $a(x) = 1 > 0$ for $x \in \mathbb R^d \setminus \overline \Omega$.

Thus it is the classical wave equation outside $\Omega$ and becomes elliptic (Laplace equation) in $\Omega$.

I couldn't find any result for this kind of problems, maybe I don't know the right key-words...

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: search for mixed hyperbolic elliptic equations. http://www.icms.org.uk/downloads/Differential/Otway.pdf

Comment: Mixed type equations.

Comment: "Transonic flow" and "Tricomi equation" are some other search terms you may find useful.